# Magento 2.2.6 - Unable to set developer mode

Tags: magento2

Im am using Magento 2.2.6 and try to switch to the dev mode (before production).

I do it like described in:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

1. rm -rf /generated/metadata/* /generated/code/*
2. bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

But at point 2. i get this error:

```
www-data@602f3683557f:~/html$ bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
Warning: include(/var/www/html/vendor/composer/../../generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
```

So, any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: You can try clearing the vendor folder `rm -rf vendor/*` and run `composer install` again to reinstall dependencies.

Comment: ? Vendor is ok ..? He have a problem to find Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php in folder enerated/code

Comment: Please remove generated folder from root     and try if it not work set dev mode using htaccess

Comment: @AndreBubner the problem is that composer's autoloader was still referencing classes that were removed from the `generated` folder, so my idea was to force composer to regenerate its autoloader which can also be done with `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution was:

rm -rf vendor/* and run composer install

Thanks to Javier Villanueva

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Comment: Great! You save my day

Answer (score 4):

Run `composer dump-autoload` in the root Magento directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get similar error when trying to compile and running this usually solves the problem:

`rm -rf var/generation var/di`

and then try to switch to developer mode again:

`bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: In Magento 2.2.6 there are no folders like : var/generation and var/di

Comment: ~/html/var$ ls -ltr
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data  96 Sep 20 04:26 page_cache
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data 160 Sep 20 04:26 composer_home
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data  64 Sep 20 04:30 session
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data  96 Sep 20 04:41 view_preprocessed
drwxrwxr-x 5 www-data www-data 160 Sep 20 05:06 log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 211 Sep 20 07:23 resource_config.json

Comment: How about removing the `pub/static/` and everything from vendor?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento ver. 2.4.5-p5 I got the same Proxy class error.

I fixed it by executing the below commands and my issue was resolved.

```
rm -rf generated/metadata/* generated/code/*

composer install

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```